# Whenever I make a change to my .aspx file, its designer.vb changes my custom control's type to System.Web.UI.UserControl

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, webforms

This is more an annoyance than anything, but it's really annoying. I have a custom control that's featured on several pages. It looks like this in the designer.vb:

```
Protected WithEvents MyCtl1 As Global.Controls.MyCtl
```

However, whenever I make a change to the HTML in the aspx file, it gets changed to

```
Protected WithEvents MyCtl1 As Global.System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

Now, this is easy to fix by reverting it manually, but the fact that it happens every time really gets on my nerves. Is there anything I can do to stop it? I'm using VS2015 right now, but it's happened in older versions too.

Edit: the tag looks like this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="MyCtl" Src="~/Controls/MyCtl.ascx"%>
```

and then a

```
<uc1:MyCtl id="MyCtl1" runat="server"></uc1:MyCtl>
```

Comment: How do you import and use it on the page?

Comment: I noticed the same thing yesterday. I couldn't figure out why it was happening. I assumed that this was something that visual studios was doing in the background.

Comment: @Andrei: It's registered with a

    <%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="MyCtl" Src="~/Controls/MyCtl.ascx"%>

and then a

    <uc1:MyCtl id="MyCtl1" runat="server"></uc1:MyCtl>

Comment: Happens to me too, not sure why, but usually solved by changing the ID of the control, saving, then changing the ID back.